# How to Make :levels Equal Specific Number of Days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a habit tracking app. Whenever a User starts a new habit he must complete 5 levels before he can consider himself a "master" at it.

I want to break down the levels (`:level`) into 5 with a total of 100 days.

```html
Levels   Days
1    =   10
2    =   15
3    =   20
4    =   25
5    =   30
```

How can I create the above relationship?

I think it's a simple question, but I can't seem to figure it out. Do I make each level its own string?: `t.string "levelone" t.string "leveltwo"`, etc?

Then do I equal that to X amount of days in the model somehow?

```html
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates :action, presence: true
end
```

```html
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
   @habits = Habit.all.order("date_started")
   @mastered_habits = current_user.habits.mastered
   @challenge_habits = current_user.habits.challenge

  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @habit = current_user.habits.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @habit = current_user.habits.build(habit_params)
    if @habit.save
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @habit.update(habit_params)
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @habit.destroy
    redirect_to habits_url
  end

  private
    def set_habit
      @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @habit = current_user.habits.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
    end

    def habit_params
      params.require(:habit).permit(:missed, :left, :level, :days, :date_started, :trigger, :action, :target, :positive, :negative, :mastered)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would like a levels [virtual attribute](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes).

```
def levels
  case days
  when 0..9
    1
  when 10..24
    2
  when 25..44
    3
  when 45..69
    4
  when 70..99
    5
  else
    6
end
```

level 6 being master level.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what your other parameters are doing but i think the general idea would be something like this

```
t.string "habitname"
t.integer "levelone"
t.integer "leveltwo" etc.
t.references :user, index: true
t.timestamps null:false
```

then in your controller to access these values

```
@habit = Habit.find(:id)
@habit.levelone = whatever days
```

Comment: Where should I put: `@habit = Habit.find(:id)
@habit.levelone = whatever days` in the controller? I expanded the controller code to give a better idea. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could just store the number of days in the model, and add a method that returns the level for that number. No need to store `:level` in the model, just `:days`.

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :action, presence: true

    def get_level
        case days
        when 0..10
           1
        when 11..15
           2
        when 16..20
           3
        when 21..25
           4
        else
           5
        end
    end

end
```